# WCAG 2.0 redundant links

Tags: html, hyperlink, accessibility, wcag, wcag2.0

I've tried searching but can't seem to find a straight answer regarding redundant links and WCAG compliance.

I have a product collection/category page with a list of products. Each product has a product image, name, price, and 'Learn More' button. The product image and 'Learn More' button both go to the same destination.

```html
<div class="product-wrap">
    <div class="product-image">
        <a href="product-page.html"><img src="product-image.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="product-name">
        Sample Product Name
    </div>
    <div class="product-price">
        $29.99
    </div>
    <div class="product-learn-more">
        <a href="product-page.html">Learn More</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Based off what I've read having adjacent links go to the same location is not compliant.

I can't link the whole product since I don't want everything clickable so I'm not sure what my options are.

Does anything have any idea how to make this compliant?

Comment: [Cross-posted to UX SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/125634/17023)

Answer (score 3):

The [guidance from W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H2.html) states that you should wrap the image and the text in a single anchor element. They also state that you must not omit the `alt` attribute, as this would cause failure of [SC 1.1.1.](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#text-equiv-all)

If this isn't an option in your instance, one possible solution that comes to mind is to use the [`aria-hidden`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.2/#aria-hidden) attribute on your `div.product-image`.

> Authors MAY, with caution, use aria-hidden to hide visibly rendered content from assistive technologies only if the act of hiding this content is intended to improve the experience for users of assistive technologies by removing redundant or extraneous content.
>
> https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.2/#aria-hidden